# Cron trigger to run every 1 hour?

Tags: spring, triggers, cron

Can anyone suggest a way to set a Cron trigger to run every 1 hour?
I tried to do something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *")
```

but when I run the server I get Error :

```
Error 404--Not Found
```

What is wrong in this cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following `cron` statement:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "59 * * * * *")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try any one of these:

- 0 0 0/1 * * ?
- 0 0 * * * ?

This means 0 seconds 0 minutes on change of every hour.